# C++ container (or fuction) that can store numbered integer values

Tags: c++, containers

is there a container or a faction that allows me to store integer values while also having a set number or name on each value. What I need exactly is a way to sort for, example, the following values: [12, 3, 8, 32, 13] but keep track of which is which, eg. that 12 is v1, 8 is v3 ect.

Comment: Have you read the chapter in C++ book that explains how to use a map or an unordered map?

Comment: depending upon the queries what you need to make later and the uniquness of the integers(*key*'s), you probaly wanna end up using: [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) or `std::multimap` or `std::unordered_multimap` or simply `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>`

Comment: @JeJo please hover your mouse over the "add a comment" button cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to implement is a *mapping* (i.e. a list of ways in which thing *A* maps to thing *B*), and C++ provides plenty of map containers for you.

For example:

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    // Map of integer values to version number
    std::map<int, int> values{
       {12, 1},
       {3,  ?},
       {8,  3},
       {32, ?},
       {13, ?}
    };
}
```

Your book will explain how to use this properly.

Answer (score 3):

just a simple example :

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::map<int, std::string> m;

  m[1] = "un";
  m[123] = "a lot";

  std::cout << "1 : " << m[1] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "0 : " << m[0]  << std::endl; // that add a new entry for 0 in 'm' with an empty string and returns that empty string
  std::cout << "123 : " << m[123] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

the execution is :

```
1 : un
0 : 
123 : a lot
```